# React 18 seo setting

Tags: reactjs

How to set seo for projects with React 18 and styled-components. Do not use nextjs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using React.js and would not use Next.js then, React Helmet might help you with some Meta tags manipulation. You can checkout more at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet. If you want to follow a tutorial you can check out this https://abbasimusab2000.medium.com/using-react-helmet-in-react-js-1ef8acc7ec9